# react-bootstrap-table: hand over parent function to rowEvent

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap table, and want to open a modal once a row is clicked. The row event is triggered, however the parent function within the row event, which I use to open the modal, is not triggered. It seems that I can access the props in this object, since I get the console output below. Why is the function not triggered?

```
const rowEvents = {
onClick: (e, row, rowIndex) => {
  console.log("row event triggered, here is my function:", this.props)
  this.props.onClickShowModal
}}

<BootstrapTable { ...props.baseProps } hover={true} striped={true} { ...paginationTableProps } rowEvents={rowEvents}/>
```

console output:

```
row event triggered, here is my function: {onClickShowModal: ƒ}
```

Answer (score 0):

it works now, when I add the parentheses at the end. I assume that this is needed, so that the function is handed over, and not an object, but I dont understand the difference yet.

```
 const rowEvents = {
    onClick: (e, row, rowIndex) => {
      this.props.onClickShowModal()
      }   
    }
```